# How do I discard changes in new Google Apps Script IDE?

Tags: google-apps-script, ide

I've been switched over to the new Google Apps Script IDE.

If I have multiple .gs and html files in one script document I used to be able to make changes on a file a close that without saving.  Now the tabs are no more and you click directly on the filename and all you can do is undo until the file is reverted.

Is there a way to revert in one step?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new code editor has no way to close an unsaved files' edit session.  There is no good way to revert back to the last saved content.  The only option you have is to close or refresh the browser tab.  If you close or refresh the browser tab and you have other unsaved open file sessions that you *want* saved, then make sure to save the ones you want.

Comment: OK thanks for the confirmation. Bit annoying but I guess saving the ones I want and refreshing is the only way